# Drupal7 .install script not working

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to convert my module from drupal6 to drupal 7 this is my code. The database table is not created.

```
function example_install() {
  drupal_install_schema('example');
}
/**
 * Implements hook_schema().
 */
function example_schema() {
  $schema['example'] = array(
    'description' => 'example settings',
    'fields' => array(
      'name' => array(
        'description' => 'name',
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'length' => '255',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),

      'age' => array(
        'description' => 'age',
        'type' => 'int',
    'size' => 'tiny',
        'not null' => TRUE,
      ),
)    ,
);
  return $schema;
}
```

Can any one explain whats wrong.

Comment: errors ? anything at all happen when you run this ?

Comment: No it just says the module is enabled.

Answer (score 8):

You don't want to run `drupal_install_schema()` yourself in Drupal 7, `hook_schema()` is called automatically if it exists in the .install file. That will probably cause a few problems but you'd still expect the table to be created at least once.

Once you've removed `hook_install()` try uninstalling (not just disabling) your module, then re-enabling it. I recommend the [`Devel module`](http://drupal.org/project/devel) to do this as it provides a page (devel/reinstall) where you can easily force a reinstall of a module.

If you don't want to do that though, go to the modules page, disable the module, then click the 'Uninstall' tab at the top to uninstall it fully. Then go back to the modules page and re-enable it.

Doing this should force Drupal to re-run your `hook_schema()` script and the table should be created.

Comment: This post also helped me because in this instance I had been trying to create a database that was referring to invalid indexes. The table simply didn't create and I didn't find any debugging output to see what is going wrong. Finally the fixing the 'indexes' and doing an uninstall recreated the lot.